# Search, count and position of the count in a file

Tags: shell, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I am not an expert with Linux, but looking at different posts in various forums, I have been trying to write a script to match pattern of characters occurring together in a file. 
My file has approximately 200 million characters (upper and lower case), with about 50 characters per line. I have merged all the lines together to make it one line using

```
tr -d '\n' < input.txt > oneLineInput.txt
```

This gets all the characters in my file to the same line without spaces.

I am trying to count the number of times the specific characters occur together. For example, in the file below

```
IamTryingtobuildascriptfortrestingthetyposinmysentence
```

I am trying to look for the pattern 'tr' that occurs in the sentence. The script I have now is

```
grep -o -i oneLineInput.txt -e tr | sort | uniq -c
```

The above script works perfectly fine for a small file, but when I try to run it on my actual file with more than 200 million characters, it takes ages to finish the task (I lost patience and did not check the total time taken).

1. Is there a way I can optimize the code?

I have also been trying to get the position of the match. For example, in the above example file, 'tr' is starts on 4th and 27th position.

1. Is it possible to get the position of index as a number in the output.

Thank you

Comment: I am able to count the occurrences of 'tr' in my original file using the above script. But, i miss a few counts when the occurrence of 't' is on the last position of a line and 'r' is the first character of the next line.

Comment: By removing the newlines you created situations where `t` at the end of one line and `r` at the start of another will now be counted as an occurrence of `tr`. Is that what you want? What if there was some other space char between `t` and `r` - should they be counted as a `tr` then? Either way, merging the lines wasn't a useful step, it's just as easy to simply ignore spaces if that's the desired behavior.

Comment: The file I have does not have any space. The pattern in question can also be found on two consecutive lines. Hence, I merged the lines.
@ Ed Morton, how do I ignore spaces??? Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `-F'[Tt][[:space:]]*[Rr]'` as the FS to match and `-v RS='^$'` as the record separator with GNU awk (other awks have other ways). `[[:space:]]*` means zero or more space characters and that RS setting tells gawk to treat the whole file as a single string.

Comment: I did not understand much of the statement As I am not an expert in scripting, I am trying to understand the working code. Thanks for the tip, I now know its possible.

Comment: Just change `awk -F"[Tt][Rr]" '{print NF-1}' oneLineInput.txt` to `awk -v RS='^$' -F"[Tt][[:space:]]*[Rr]" '{print NF-1}' multiLineInput.txt`.

Comment: Woah... thats brilliant. Works flawless. Now its my turn to understand the basics :)

Comment: Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robins. awk is the standard UNIX tool for text manipulation, it will pay off repeatedly to know it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` will show how many `tr` you have in the `oneLineInput.txt`

```
awk -F"[Tt][Rr]" '{print NF-1}' oneLineInput.txt
2
```

---

To get the position:

```
awk -F"[Tt][Rr]" 'BEGIN {print "hit\tposition"} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {p+=length($i);print ++a"\t"p+1+(a-1)*2}}' oneLineInput.txt
hit     position
1       4
2       27
```

To get the position: `p+1+(a-1)*2`
`p` incremental length of fields
`+1` since `tr` comes after the length of the field.
`(a-1)*2` number of hits -1 multiple length of data to search `tr` = `2` characters.

Comment: That was just incredible. I cannot thank you enough. I have to decipher and learn how it works. The script I had used to take ages for the size of files I had. 
Unfortunately I cannot upvote because of my reputation.
Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @biowizz you are welcome. It takes lots of time to learn all the nice tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that you could do it using awk:

```
{ 
    while (match($0, /[Tt][Rr]/)) {
        ++n
        m += RSTART
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
        printf "match %d: position %d\n", n, m + n - 1
    }
}
```

`match` stores the position of the first match in the variable `RSTART` and the length of the match in `RLENGTH`. `n` keeps a count of the number of matches. `substr` is used to remove the match from the start of the string. The position to be printed must be offset by `n - 1`.

Output:

```
$ awk -f matches.awk file
match 1: position 4
match 2: position 27
```

Comment: Thank you. This works nicely too. But is slightly slower than the previous answer. Nice to know different approaches to do the same task.